# How do you make a transparent latch in Chisel?

Tags: chisel

Here is my best guess, but it doesn't look like the generated behavioral Verilog will result in a simple transparent latch when synthesized:

```
// DXP Latch
val dxp = config(2) & config(0)
val latch = Reg( lut.io.out )
val out = Mux( dxp, latch, lut.io.out )
```

I appreciate your ideas on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chisel does not support latches. `Reg()` will only generate edge-triggered state elements.

If you really want latches, you would have to modify the backend of Chisel to understand a new `Latch()` construct and generate the appropriate Verilog. However, this will take you down a long rabbit hole of difficulties, the first of which is you would probably be throwing away the synchronous, edge-triggered timing model (that allows things like the C++ emulator to work).

In our experiences, any critical applications that needed some of the properties of latches will get automatically handled by the synthesis tools (like time-borrowing).

Comment: Looks like in our case, our synthesis tools are indeed turning the behavioral Verilog generated by the above Chisel code into a transparent latch.  Thanks, synthesis tool!